# derive the expectation of exponential function $e^{-\left\Vert \mathbf{x} - V\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{a}\right\Vert^2}$ or its upper bound

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, exponential-function, normed-spaces

I need to analyze this expectation with respect to $n$-dimensional random vectors $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{C}^n$.

$$E=\int_\mathbf{x} e^{-\left\Vert \mathbf{x} - V\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{a}\right\Vert^2} p_\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{x}) d\mathbf{x}$$

where $V$ is a fixed $n\times n$ [unitary matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix) and $\mathbf{a}$ is a fixed $n\times 1$ vector. Note that $V$ is not positive definite.

It is clear that $E$ must be a function of $\mathbf{a}$ and $V$.

1) Is there any non trivial distribution $p_\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{x})$ that can facilite the calculation of $E$ ? I have tried the uniform distribution over a fixed $(n-1)$-sphere without success.

2) Is there any inequality that can yield upper bound $E$ by a function of $\mathbf{a}$ and $V$. I mean something like  $E = f(\mathbf{a},V) < g(\mathbf{a},V)$ without having $f(\mathbf{a},V)$ ?

I appreciate any hints and references.

Comment: If $x$ is a multivariate gaussian there is an explicit formula for the expectation.

Comment: @kimchilover thanks. However could you please give me more hints ? Do you mean if $x$ is multivariate gaussian, $x-Vx+a$ is also multivariate gaussian and invariant to rotation ? But I dont see how we can take advantage of this property.

Comment: Think about the norming constant for the multivariate normal: it is a determinant of a certain matrix, raised to a certain power.  Your integral has the same form, so it's value is also a determinant of a related matrix, and so on.  How would you calculate $\int_{\mathbb R} \exp(x^2/10)\phi(x)dx$ where $\phi$ is a standard gaussian?  Answer: By recognizing the integrand as a multiple of another gaussian density.